# Related to DropBox API

Tags: ipad, dropbox-api

I am using Dropbox API in my iPad app.Means i am accessing Dropbox folder and displaying files in my app, By selecting a file from that Dropbox app folder am using it into my app. Now i want to submit it to AppStore. So before submitting it to AppStore. How can i submit it to production in DropBox site.I have seen it in Dropbox site but i didn't get it. If anyone know please help me. 
[image]

And at the time of logout am using
 [[DBSession sharedSession] unlinkAll];  but after login if am i goto dropbox it is showing 
the below screen. But i want to show login screen.It is showing login screen when i select "change". To show login at first time what i need to do. which methd will call when i click on change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply for production status by clicking on the "Apply for production status" link on your app's options page, and filling out the form.

To get to your app's options page, go here:
[Developers - Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps)
Then, click the "Options" link to the right of the app you want to apply for production with.

Be sure to give clear, complete answers to the questions on the form. You can find more information about applying for production here:
[Core concepts - Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/core)

Regarding your edit, although unrelated to the first question, it sounds like you want to be able to immediately direct the user to the login screen, as they may be signed into the wrong account. The Dropbox API doesn't currently have any such way to do this, rather, you should just let the user use the "change" button themselves if they wish to change accounts.

Comment: Hi Greg. I edited my question. If you know how to , let me know please.